# LINQ Lambda Expressions

Tags: linq

I was wondering if there is a good tutorial out there dedicated solely for Lambda Expressions.
I have used query expressions and Lambda expressions at times but wasn't able to find
a solid tutorial/book solely for Linq Lambda Expressions.

Comment: What aspects do you need the most clarification on? There is always MSDN for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx I would also recommend looking into how lambda expressions and anonymous functions are used in more functional languages such as JavaScript or Lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to try some of the LINQ expressions out in [LinqPad](http://Linqpad.net) and then click on the lambda button to see how they are translated under the covers. Rinse and repeat. If you want to grab a bunch of LINQ samples in LinqPad, go to the samples tab and select the download option. There are several book's worth of samples available there to play with (including the ones from my LINQ in Action).

Comment: Thanks Jim. Do you know if LinqPad has a way such that you write a SQL Statement and it converts to LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a lambda expression and the LINQ fluent query syntax with which you can use lambda expressions.

If you're after information about the LINQ fluent query syntax, then specifically you'll want to learn about the standard query operators that are provided by LINQ.

You could start here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx

You could also get more in-depth information about how the standard query operators could be implemented in Jon Skeet's blog - http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx